# Printing (physically) vertical lines for indentation

Tags: printing

I'm trying to print out a hard copy of some code. It's very long (~18 pages) and nesting goes down several levels, so it would be a big help trying to parse things visually across several pages if I had some sort of visual marker delineating the indentation throughout the document.

SublimeText as well as some other editors do this in their GUI but I haven't figured out a way to extend that to the printed version of a given document.

A screen cap of the lines I'm referencing:

[image: three vertical lines]

Any ideas for how to print this out?

PS I'm working in black-and-white, so coloring is off the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the file through a script which makes a marked-up copy, e.g,

- first, expand all tabs (to simplify the second step) and
- then change leading whitespace to put a marker at what would be tab-stops

The [`expand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html) program is useful for the first step, and [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) for the second.  So a filter might look like

```
#!/bin/sh
TAB=$(echo X| tr X '\t')
expand "$@" | sed -e ':loop' -e "s/^\(\.${TAB}\)*\(    \)/\1.${TAB}/" -e 't loop |expand
```

This puts a "." at tab-stops.  You might like a "|" better, but it might be too noticeable.

You would use it like

```
myfilter myfile | lpr
```